Get Object from Amazon S3 without exception
I'm using C# SDK for .NET Core to fetch objects from the store with GetObjectAsync. However, it might be that there is no such object that the program requests. In this case, GetObjectAsync throws AmazonS3Exception with ErrorCode == "NoSuchKey".
But this slows down the program, as it is normal when an object does not exist.
Can I force the SDK not to throw exceptions but instead let me inspect the response and figure out if the object was found or not?

The SDK throwing an exception here is typically how things are expected to work... it's their way of stating that the response has a failure code. My suggestion would be to put the GetObjectAsync inside a try/catch block that grabs any AmazonS3Exception and gracefully handles it in whatever way you want. The caught exception should have all the details about the response that you want to examine.
var bar;

try
{
    bar = store.GetObjectAsync(foo, foobar, cancellationToken);
}
catch(AmazonS3Exception ex)
{
    //handle the exception here
}


Thanks. That's how it works now but it's not what I want. Throwing and catching an exception takes time and I would prefer it not to be thrown at all.

I'm not sure what you mean by it takes time.... the processing impact of a try-catch is pretty minimal, and there's almost always better places to look first for performance improvements. As far as not throwing at all... The only way to get past that would be to delve into the code for the .GetObjectAsync method itself and overwrite it with a new implementation. Doing that to 3rd party library simply because you don't want to try/catch would be really inadvisable.
